# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, windows, windows-8, firebird

I am trying to use Firebird 2.5.2.26539 with:

- Windows 8
- Apache 2.2.22
- PHP 5.4.10

When i enable the extensions of firebird in php:

```
- extension=php_interbase.dll
- extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

I get these errors:

> [26-Dec-2012 12:08:11 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_interbase.dll' - Impossible to locate the specified module.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>
> [26-Dec-2012 12:08:13 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' -  Impossible to locate the specified module.
>   in Unknown on line 0

if i make PHP -a in command line, the error message is different: cannot find fbclient.dll.

I have the flamerobin running and it opens the database. So i copy the fbclient.dll to the PHP root path.
Then the errors change to:

> [26-Dec-2012 11:55:46 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_interbase.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>
> [26-Dec-2012 11:55:46 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - %1  is not a valid Win32 application.
>   in Unknown on line 0

Can anyone help me on this one? I suspect that this version of Firebird still does not have the correct extensions made for the PHP.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using 64bit Apache / PHP but 32bit Firebird (or vice versa)?

Comment: Try copy all this three files to c:\windows\system32\ or to apache bit folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cli and Apache PHP run with two different configuration files. That will explain the lacking error message in CLI mode. The likelihood is the extensions for this application where not stored in the PHP extension folder. I'm not versed with the configurations under windows so you may need to google for the Windows PHP extension directory and ensure your extension file is there.

Judging by your error the path is "C:\Program files(x86)\PHP\ext\

Please ensure your extension files are there before attempting to load them.

Comment: Moving the new dll file into the extension folder likely caused a new error before the execution of the extensions this the appearance of an error change :)

Comment: Hello,In windows, cli and apache PHP modes have the same ini file. Also i do have the extensions of pdo_firebird and firebird in the ext directory. The problem is different.

Comment: The problem was the fbclient.dll from the FB 64 bits installation. I just got the fbclient.dll from 32bits, copy it into the PHP root and it solved the problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue: I changed the PATH for php directory to switch default php version. This resulted that fbclient.dll was searched in the NEW PATH directory and NOT in the php directory where Apache runs php.

Even the extension_dir seems to be correct, but php_interbase.dll does NOT pick the fbclient.dll of its parent folder, but the one from the PATH.

Answer (score 6):

I am repeating the comment (which some might miss) by Nenhum Pois é above, because it is the real solution to the problem:

> The problem was the fbclient.dll from the FB 64 bits installation. I just got the fbclient.dll from 32bits, copy it into the PHP root and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you run on Windows check if your extension is compiled with the same Visual Studio compiler version as your PHP interpreter.

From PHP download page https://windows.php.net/download

- PHP 7.3 = VC15
- PHP 7.1 = VC14
- PHP 5.6 = VC11

Whereas the MongoDB extension for examples is compiled with VC11, see https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.16/windows and check the DLL list filename for `-vc11-`