# PHP xdebug on NetBeans doesn't work

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I did 3 days of research and couldn't really solve my issue.

Here is my xdebug setting in php.ini

```
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

[image: My NetBeans run-configuration]

One thing I notice writing this question was even when I'm debugging the port is always set to `8000` when I set it to `9000`:

[image]

[image]

So I thought maybe NetBeans is pointing to a wrong php.ini ? I run `phpinfo()` in my test.php and it gave me this:

[image]

Now I'm totally lost. What should I do to make xdebug to work on NetBeans?

**EDIT:** I'm using internal web-server on NetBeans

**EDIT:** Things started to progress but now NetBeans give me this weird output:

```
"D:\bit_nami\php\php.exe" "-S" "localhost:9001"
[Tue Aug 08 02:42:38 2017] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\bit_nami\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - 占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙 占쏙옙占� 찾占쏙옙 占쏙옙 占쏙옙占쏙옙占싹댐옙.
 in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Aug 08 02:42:38 2017] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\bit_nami\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - 占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙 占쏙옙占� 찾占쏙옙 占쏙옙 占쏙옙占쏙옙占싹댐옙.
 in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Aug 08 02:42:38 2017] PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Aug 08 02:42:38 2017] PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Aug 08 02:42:38 2017] Failed to listen on localhost:9001 (reason: 액세스 권한에 의해 숨겨진 소켓에 액세스를 시도했습니다.
)
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\bit_nami\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - 占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙 占쏙옙占� 찾占쏙옙 占쏙옙 占쏙옙占쏙옙占싹댐옙.
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\bit_nami\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - 占쏙옙占쏙옙占쏙옙 占쏙옙占� 찾占쏙옙 占쏙옙 占쏙옙占쏙옙占싹댐옙.
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
Done.
```

Comment: Do you use an apache or the internal webserver of netbeans?

Comment: powerpete - I'm using internal webserver on netbeans

Comment: Write `zend_extension=...xdebug...` instead of `extension=...xdebug...`

Comment: @KannaKim find extension=xdebug.so in your php.ini or find it in files like php.d\20-xdebug.ini and comment it out. Then add zend_extension=xdebug.so instead. This should solve `Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0` issue. For php load dynamic library visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14042516/2406912). Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to match port three different places:

1. php.ini file
2. Netbeans > Options > php > Debugging > Debugger Port
3. Netbeans > Project Properties > Run Configuration > Advance Web Configuration > Debugger Proxy Port (Assuming you are running Local Web Site (running on local web server)).

Then make sure to set xdebug.remote_host or xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 . Setting both of them does not work.

Following setting is recommended for php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name=xdebug-profile-cachegrind.out-%H-%R
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 128
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

For more information visit [How To Configure XDebug](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug)

Comment: I can't find any   Advance Web Configuration in Netbeans > Project Properties  > run config [this is how my run conf looks like](https://imgur.com/a/DVeiS) . I'm using Netbean IDE 8.2

Comment: You need to change the Port to 9000 if you are running Built-in Web Server. It is not usually the case though. My answer is for when using local web server (most common case).

Comment: oh thanks, and by the way 2 questions 
1. "Then make sure to set xdebug.remote_host or xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 . Setting both of them does not work." << my xdebug.remote_host has value of = 127.0.0.1 not a 0 or 1 isn't the remote_host supposed to be IP address or localhost? 

2. should I match my port to 9001? since your recommended php.ini has remote_port = 9001

Comment: The xdebug.remote_host can be IP address or host name known to your server. The xdebug.remote_port should be any open network port. Usually 9000 or 9001 for xdebug. But remember to match it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Netbeans with php and XDebug (on Windows/Apache). It's working fine. (I checked it also with the Netbeans Built-In Web Server)

The relevant part of my php.ini:

```
zend_extension=C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.35-0\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.6-5.4-vc9.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

In the default Setup (with the Built-in Server) the browser talks over Port 8000 to the PHP Built-In Server and the PHP Build-In Server talks over Port 9000 to the Netbeans debugger Part.

So on some Windows Systems you have to open/allow these two ports in the firewall settings for the php executable.